# Is there a name for chord shape 322450 on guitar?

Tags: guitar, chords

[image]

This shape is playing an Em (322450), but I'm not used to see it and it doesn't match the common E and A movable shapes I see all the time.

Is this common with some specific styles?

---

Edit:

I should have added this at the beginning:
- This is the original song (tuned down for live):

- This is the guitar cover with the 'odd' chord shape:

you can see that shape around 1:07

Comment: It's uncommon to me too. Movable, but the top string would need muting. Something of a G6.

Comment: @Tim -- it took me a minute to catch up to you about the muting: muting to make it movable. It kind of looks like the top string is being muted by the side of the index finger in the image. If OP saw this labelled as an **Em** somewhere, it is an **Em** in first inversion, but it seems more likely to me that it would be used as a **G6**, as you say.

Comment: Why a G6? Other than the fact it's got a G bass, it's just root & 5th all the way up GBEBEE

Comment: @Tetsujin -- B is the 3rd of **G**, so 1-3-6: an acceptable **G6** ;)

Comment: The other guitar is playing an E5 at that time; the progression being A5-G5-E5, this is most likely an Em

Comment: 'The other guitar'? Where did that come into the question

Comment: It feels like it should form part of a Pink Floyd style pedal, like their Em structures that sit with a pedal D G at the top; think Wish you were Here etc

Comment: Emin first inversion, similar to G6 (no 5th).  The hand form is most like a G6 but the open string would make it difficult to translate up the neck (not a movable chord form).  On the other hand, your 5 on the B string is just doubling the open E.  Any reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Em/G or maybe G6, but not a particularly nice sounding one, IMO. It's less muddy, if you leave out at least the second-lowest string, for example 3x24xx, but then you'll have to mute the non-sounding strings, maybe finger-pick. I use those kinds of chords when I want to have particular inversions and voice-leading for the bass, and/or a specific highest note. But then it's only for a specific moment in that specific bass/harmony/melody motion.

Which styles use that... "fingerstyle" maybe? I think fingerstyle guitarists seem to be more careful about inversions than players of some other styles. :)

Comment: It's in a 70s rock song ("This is the one", from Thin Lizzy); one guitar does power chords and the other one plays the same chords, but in a higher register. I saw a video with that shape and I have been intrigued by it